Plotting a bar with variable density represented by a color gradient
The mass of a thin bar that has the following density function, rho.
rho[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x (2 - x), 1 <= x <= 2}}]

I would like to create a bar that represents the density functions by a color gradient, say between white (rho=0) and brown (rho=1).  For example, the following code generates a bar with a color gradient from (white to brown) but the color gradient is not representing rho yet.
RegionPlot[-3 < x < 3 && 0 < y < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Blend[{White, Brown}, {1, x}]], 
 BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.004]}, Frame -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> .1]


I'm not sure how to incorporate rho into the code.  The result should be a bar that is brown in the middle and smooths out to white on both ends.
If you can point me in the right direction, that should suffice.  Thank you!  Perhaps starting with RegionPlot[] is not the right choice.

How about using DensityPlot instead?
rho[x_]:=Piecewise[{{x^2,0<=x<=1},{x (2-x),1<=x<=2}}];

DensityPlot[rho[x],{x,0,2},{y,0,0.2},AspectRatio->Automatic,
ColorFunction->(Blend[{White,Brown},#]&),
Frame->None,Axes->False,BoundaryStyle->{{Black,Thickness[.004]}},
Exclusions->None]


